# What is the most elegant way to create a JSON data structure

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x

I'm a relatively noob at Python coding.   I'm actually a network engineer that toys around with various scripting.

Anyway,  I'm creating various scripts to submit JSON requests to some webservers.   I'm trying to figure out what the most elegant way to do that is.   The JSON data structure is often 4 or 5 levels deep.

I could just create something like the following.
'''

```
json_object = {}
Json_object['first level'] = {}
json_object['first_level']['A'] = "data"
json_object['first_level']['B'] = "other data"
json_object['second level'] = []
```

'''
And so on.  That seems pretty kludgy.   What do people usually do to make this a little cleaner?  I thought about maybe doing a get to the web server to get the data structure but then I thought that might not be the best way either.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. This question is a bit unclear. What is the expected request body by the server and what problem are you trying to avoid?

Comment: Hi Ryan,   I'm trying to figure out what the most pythonic way of creating a moderately complex json array would be.  Do I just explicitly create it or is there a good programmatic way to do it?    

I'm guessing that just explicitly creating it is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: It all depends on where the data is coming from. If you're setting the values yourself in your code then something like what you have is sensible. With your given example you could even make it briefer by having `json_object = {"first_level": {"A": "data", "B": "other data"}, "second_level": []}`.

However if the data is coming from elsewhere then you may need to do something different and that depends on how it's structured.

Answer (score 0):

The below json object can be used :

```
json_object = {
    first_level : {
       [
          A : "data",
       ],
       [
          B : "other data",
       ]
    },
    second_level : []
}
```